# KSH to keep on refreshing the terminal screen in UNIX

Tags: unix

I want to check autosys job status at real time, like i will run one ksh and all the data should keep on refreshing on the same screen , just like a real time monitoring system...

Suggest a way to do that.

Comment: What kind of output does the job produce? If possible, redirect that to a file, and use e.g. `tail -f filename` if the new output generated should be appended to the existing one, or an infinite loop if you would like to fully refresh the screen with the last N lines (e.g. `while true; do clear; tail -n N  filename; sleep 5; done`).

Comment: using tail -f.. it will keep on adding new lines from the bottom,,, i want the existing terminal to be refreshed and doing a scroll up should not show older data